# Restore Microsoft Teams Channel via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have a service which utilises MS Graph API and I'm looking for a way to  delete and restore deleted channel(s) using MS Graph API.

To delete a channel I am utilising `/teams/{id}/channels/{id}` Graph API, however I am struggling to find a way to recover deleted channel.

In the description of above call it is mentioned that data is stored for couple of weeks (21 days since delete) so there should be a way to recover it?

I know it can be done using Teams application, however I would like to do it via Graph API.

I checked below article and Graph documentation but was not able to find suitable solution. Am I missing something or this has not been implemented yet?

> https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uclobby/2018/08/21/restore-deleted-teams-and-channels-from-microsoft-teams/
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Currently, Graph APIs to restore channel is not available.

Comment: Hi @Wajeed-MSFT thanks for that. Do you know by any chance if this is something we can expect in the next year or there are no plans around it at the moment?

Comment: No. Currently, we do not have any plans for Graph APIs to restore deleted channels.